# Access Sorcery oauth response data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, sorcery

I'm using Sorcery gem with External submodule. For some reason I'm not getting an email back from Facebook and I'm pretty sure I have things configured correctly. I'm trying to troubleshoot this further but I can't figure out how to read what data IS being returned via oauth to verify where things are breaking down. Where can I pry in and read this info? Thanks!

Here is my sorcery config.

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.submodules = [:external]

Rails.application.config.sorcery.configure do |config|

  config.external_providers = [:facebook, :google]

  config.facebook.key = "#{Rails.application.secrets.sorcery_facebook_key}"
  config.facebook.secret = "#{Rails.application.secrets.sorcery_facebook_secret}"
  config.facebook.callback_url = "#{Rails.application.secrets.sorcery_facebook_callback_url}"
  config.facebook.user_info_path = "me?fields=email,first_name,last_name"
  config.facebook.user_info_mapping = {:email => "email"}
  config.facebook.access_permissions = ["email"]
  config.facebook.scope = "email"
  config.facebook.display = "popup"
  config.facebook.api_version = "v2.5"

  config.user_config do |user|
    user.authentications_class = Authentication
  end

  config.user_class = User
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, technically this answers the question of how to find out what is being returned.

Inside your oauth controller if you call `access_token.get('me?fields=email')` or whatever fields you're wanting you'll get a response with a URL field set. Copy that URL into a browser and you'll get a JSON list of your data. In my case I get nothing with email but I'm able to return first_name, last_name, name. Not quite sure why I still can't get email, but hopefully this helps somebody troubleshoot in the future.

Another way would be to build the URL yourself if you have the `access_token` available.

`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<access token goes here>&fields=first_name,last_name,email`

Access token is retrievable with `@access_token.token` from oauth controller.

**UPDATE**

So silly...I had the config correct, but apparently had never logged out of Facebook since I'd made the proper corrections. Logging out and having oauth connect again seems to have fixed things.